# Replacing Merge in SQL Server with some other code to have the same functionality

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I replace the merge query with some other code in SQL Server 2012 in below code to get the same functionality.

```
 MERGE ReprocessPRESs with (ROWLOCK) AS TARGET   
 USING   
 (      
 SELECT @PRId AS PRId,      
   Val AS ESId,  
   GETDATE() as CreateDate      
 FROM @ESIds      
 ) AS SOURCE (PRId,ESId,CreateDate)      
 ON TARGET.PRId= SOURCE.PRId AND TARGET.ESId = SOURCE.ESId
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET       
  AND SOURCE.PRId = @PRId 
   THEN INSERT (PRId,ESId,CreateDate) 
  VALUES (PRId,ESId,CreateDate)      
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE       
  AND TARGET.PRId = @PRId
   THEN DELETE;
```

Where @ESIds is a User defined type of IntList

Basically it should update, insert or delete accordingly.

Comment: What you want is called an "Upsert". Aaron Bertrand has a great number of [articles on `MERGE`](//sqlblog.org/merge) and what you should be doing instead:

Comment: @ThomA thanks for the reply, could you tell about the Delete as well in this query? So AFAIU, It should update only the createdate for any rows matching with PRId and ESId, Insert if no row is found by the given PRId?

Comment: @ThomA I just want to understand the following conditions: (1) WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET   THEN INSERT (2) WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE  THEN DELETE

Comment: `INSERT`/`DELETE` with a `NOT EXISTS` on the respective table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact same code as separate statements would be:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT ReprocessPRESs WITH (ROWLOCK)
SELECT
  @PRId AS PRId,      
  SOURCE.Val AS ESId,  
  GETDATE() as CreateDate      
FROM @ESIds SOURCE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ReprocessPRESs TARGET  -- you should add UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK here
    WHERE TARGET.PRId = @PRId
      AND TARGET.ESId = SOURCE.ESId
);
     
DELETE TARGET
FROM ReprocessPRESs TARGET WITH (ROWLOCK)
WHERE TARGET.PRId = @PRId
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @ESIds SOURCE
    WHERE TARGET.ESId = SOURCE.Val
);

COMMIT;
```

Having said that, you would be advised to use `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` hints on the inner side of the `EXISTS` in the `INSERT` section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So does this mean first Insert query will run and after that the Delete query will run separately?

Comment: Not really, `MERGE` is a kind of a specialized operator which decides row by row whether to insert, update, delete